# Angularjs toolbar commands- disable and disable buttons

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to disable and enable button: 
for instance: If I click on Modify button I want to disable it and Enable Save button and if I click on Save button I want to enable Modify button and disable Save button. Thank you.

Below the Angularjs code:

```
angular.module('virtoCommerce.catalogModule')
.controller('virtoCommerce.catalogModule.categoriesItemsListController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        var isFieldEnabled = true;
        blade.updatePermission = 'catalog:update';        

    ... (more codes but not included)

        var formScope;
        $scope.setForm = function (form) { formScope = form; }

        //Save the prices entered by the user.
        function savePrice()
        {
            //TODO: Save the price information.
        }

    function isDirty() {
            return blade.hasUpdatePermission();
     };    

        //function enablePriceField
        function enablePriceField() {
            var inputList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var inputList2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputList);

            if (isFieldEnabled == true) {                  
                for (i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
                    var row = inputList2[i];

                    if (row.id == "priceField") {
                        row.disabled = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {                   
                for (i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {

                    var row = inputList2[i];

                    if (row.id == "priceField") {
                        row.disabled = true;
                    }                
                }
            }

            //Set the flag to true or false    
            if (isFieldEnabled == true) {
                isFieldEnabled = false
            } else {
                isFieldEnabled = true;
            }
        }


     var formScope;
     $scope.setForm = function (form) { formScope = form; }

     function canSave() {
            return isDirty() && formScope && formScope.$valid;
     }           


     //Angular toolbar commands
        blade.toolbarCommands = [
            {
                 name: "platform.commands.modify",
                 icon: 'fa fa-pencil',
                 executeMethod: function () { enablePriceField();},
                 canExecuteMethod: function () { return true; }
             },
             {
                 name: "platform.commands.save",
                 icon: 'fa fa-floppy-o',
                 executeMethod: function () { savePrice(); },
                 canExecuteMethod: canSave,
                 permission: blade.updatePermission
             }];
 }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I see how your code is related to the question, but you can enable/disable a button programatically using the ngDisabled directive (see the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)).

In your controller, intialize $scope.enableSave = true (of false, as you want). Then in your html:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!enableSave" ng-click="enableSave=!enableSave">Save</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="enableSave" ng-click="enableSave=!enableSave">Modify</button>
```

You will toggle 'enableSave' each time you click on the active (ie. not disabled) button, which will in turn disable the button you just clicked, and enable the other one.

Comment: Than you for your response... but I my case we create dynamically the button with Angularjs instead of using HTML. if your familiar with 'virtoCommerce, buttons are created on a blade.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had not seen... I am not familiar with virtoCommerce, but if I understand correctly you want to update the 'canExecuteMethod' ? Maybe try something like that:

```
$scope.enableSave = false;
function canSave() {
    return isDirty() && formScope && formScope.$valid && $scope.enableSave;
}
```

Then for the buttons:

```
{
    name: "platform.commands.modify",
    icon: 'fa fa-pencil',
    executeMethod: function () { 
        enablePriceField();
        $scope.enableSave = true;
    },
    canExecuteMethod: function () { return !canSave(); }
},
{
    name: "platform.commands.save",
    icon: 'fa fa-floppy-o',
    executeMethod: function () { 
        savePrice(); 
        $scope.enableSave = false;
    },
    canExecuteMethod: function () { return canSave(); },
    permission: blade.updatePermission
}
```

As a side note, if isFieldEnabled is a boolean you can replace:

```
if (isFieldEnabled == true) {
    isFieldEnabled = false
} else {
    isFieldEnabled = true;
}
```

By: `isFieldEnabled = !isFieldEnabled;`